# how to create a JPanel to fill all of its parent's width?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I want to create a `JPanel` inside a `JFrame`'s `ContentPane` and I want to my `JPanel` fills all of the `contentPane`'s width.

I use `BoxLayout` for `contentPane`'s layout. Here is my code:

```
getContentPane().setLayout(new BoxLayout(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);

JPanel row = new JPanel();
row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
getContentPane().add(row);
```

Comment: any special reason to use `BoxLayout`? Why don't you use `BorderLayout`?

Comment: Well this is the default behaviour of BoxLayout. Post your `SSCCE` that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the minimum/preferred/maximum size of your panel, else the `BoxLayout` will not know how to assign the proper dimension to your pannel. See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#size).

Here's a code example you can play with. If you change the various dimensions, or comment the `setMinimumSize ()` and `setPreferredSize ()` method calls, you will see the impact on how your panel gets drawn. I set the `row` panel's background to red so you can easily see the panel during your tests.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Test");
frame.setSize (new Dimension (500, 500));
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane ();
contentPane.setLayout (new BoxLayout (contentPane, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

JPanel row = new JPanel();
row.setBackground (Color.RED);
row.setLayout(new BoxLayout(row, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
row.setMinimumSize (new Dimension (100, 100));
row.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (250, 200));
row.setMaximumSize (new Dimension (500, 300));
contentPane.add(row);

frame.setVisible (true);
```